# Checking NULL values from Database using POCO

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, poco-libraries

I'm making a query using `POCO::Data` with ODBC Connector, and I need to check for NULL values from code. In the documentation, the `Recordset` object [is supposed to have the function `isNull`](http://pocoproject.org/docs-1.5.0/Poco.Data.RecordSet.html#6293), but the code I download [here](http://pocoproject.org/download/index.html) does not contains such a method (version **1.4.6p4** right now).

How can I check then if a value is NULL with POCO library? I'm trying to create a JSON string with the data retrieved from database.

My actual code looks like this:

```
Session session(bdName, conn);
Statement select(session);  

select << sSQL;  
select.execute();

RecordSet rs(select);
bool more = rs.moveFirst();
std::size_t cols = rs.columnCount();

sResult = "{\"rowsField\":[";

while (more) {
    if (sResult.back() != '[') sResult += ','; // Not first time
    sResult += "{\"columnsField\":[";

    for (std::size_t col = 0; col < cols; ++col) {
        std::string cName = rs.columnName (col);
        std::string tName = getPocoTypeName(rs.columnType(col));
        std::string val = "";

        if (!rs[col] || rs.value(col).isEmpty()) 
            val = "NULL"; // DOES NOT WORK
        else
            val = rs[col].convert<std::string>();

        if (col != 0) sResult += ',';
        sResult += "\n{\"nameField\":\"" + cName + '\"';
        sResult += ",\"typeField\":\"" + tName + '\"';
        sResult += ",\"valueField\":\"" + val + '\"';

        sResult += "}"; // each JSON column/value
    }
    sResult += "]}\n"; // columnsField (one per row)

    more = rs.moveNext();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Nullable<std::string> val = std::string("");`

`isNull` is a member of `Nullable`, so you will be able to check if the return value is null..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I have had issues with it. I am also formatting as JSON strings. You can use `Poco::Recordset::IsNull(ColumnName)` to check if a given column name's value is NULL or not.

The below code will replace NULLS with the empty string to prevent throwing errors:

```
Poco::Data::Statement statement(session);
statement << query;
statement.execute();
Poco::Data::RecordSet record_set(statement);

bool more = record_set.moveFirst();

while (more)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> row;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < record_set.columnCount(); ++i)
    {
         std::string val = "";
         if(!record_set.isNull(record_set.columnName(i)))  
             val = record_set[i].convert<std::string>(); 
           // print results for testing
         cout << "->" << record_set.columnName(i) << ":{" << val << "}";
    }

    ret.push_back(row);
    more = record_set.moveNext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `record_set[col].isEmpty()` for checking NULL.